# Java: URL.getPath() of current "main" class returns "null", why?

Tags: java, class, url, path, program-entry-point

I'm trying to print the current path of class that executes main(), as below. I found the statements below from googling, but doesn't work in my computer(windows+intellij)

```
public class core3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new core3().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("");
            System.out.println(url);
            System.out.println(System.getProperty(url.getPath()));//print null
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Actually it prints

```
file:/D:/Documents/myproject/test01/target/classes/
null
```

Why the second print returns null? How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do expect for system properties to contain that path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[System.getProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) is for getting system properties. For example, the "java.home" system property typically points to the location of your Java installation. System properties are described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Your code is looking up a system property with key equal to your URL. You do not have such a system property defined, so `System.getProperty()` returns `null`.

If you just want to print the path, you should simply omit the `System.getProperty()` call:

```
System.out.println(url.getPath());
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why the second print returns null?

Because you are attempting to lookup a system property that doesn't exist.

This is not the way to find the path for the Main class.

What you need to do is:

1. Obtain the fully qualified (or canonical) name for the class; e.g.

   ```
     String name = Main.class.getCanonicalName();
   ```
2. Map that to the resource path for the ".class" file.  You need to:

   - replace all "." characters in full classname with "/", and then
   - append ".class".
3. Use `getResource(resourcePath)` to lookup the `URL`.

If the resulting URL is a "file:" URL, you can then use `URL::toFile()` to get the pathname in the file system.

But if the URL is a "jar:" URL (as it will be if you loaded the class from a JAR file) the the class will not have a file system pathname.

---

Note that `getClassLoader().getResource("")` gives you the path for the classloader's root directory.  That's not the path for the original class.

---

And if you want the name of the JVM class that calls your `static void main(String[])` method, then you should be able to get this using the Java 9+ `StackWalker` class ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html)).  You will need to use the option to show the hidden frames, I think.